# SSRS fails to connect SQL Server DB Hidden instance

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, database-connection, sql-server-2014

We had to set SQL Server hide instance flag as "Yes" in production to fix the violation like ADHOCdistQueries_RunValue, hideinstance etc.

But once we hide the instance, SSRS data source connection is failing. Can you please recommend options to fix this issue? We want to keep the database hidden and also make SSRS DB connection work.

How can we do it? Thanks.

> Error: The Report Server Cannot Open a Connection to the Report Server Database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing (rsReportServerUnavailable)

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It ran *completely* out of support back in 2019 (*4 years* ago). It is *long* past time you implemented your finalised upgrade plan at this point.

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Then why tag both [[tag:sql-server-2008]] and [[tag:ssrs-2008]]?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a port number instead of instance name in the connection string? That way, the SQL Server Browser service isn't used.

Comment: Dan -- This is a good answer. But we can't change all the dependent applications in production from instance name to IP/Port.  If any other option comes to your mind, feel free to share with me. Thanks.